# Angular2 Flickr JSONP

Tags: angular, jsonp

I am very new to AngularJS. I am making a Flickr public feed app using Angular2 but I encountered this problem.

I couldn't find a way to get the JSONP working. What should I do to return the JSON object?

[image]

Here's the codes

**flickr.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Jsonp, Http } from '@angular/http'; //use jsonp module to fetch the data from the api call

import 'rxjs/Rx'; // use rxjs as the observable

@Injectable()

export class FlickrService {

  url: string;
  apiKey: string = 'ffed2ef9dede27481c3195eea1be61eb';

  constructor(private _jsonp: Jsonp) {
    this.url = `https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?&api_key=${this.apiKey}&per_page=12&format=json&nojsoncallback=1`;
  }

  getFeed() {
    return this._jsonp.get(this.url)
      .map(res => res.json());
  }

  searchTag(searchTerm: string) {
    return this._jsonp.get(this.url+'&tag='+searchTerm)
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

**flickr.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FlickrService } from '../services/flickr.service';
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'flickr',
  templateUrl: './flickr.component.html'
})
export class FlickrComponent {
  feedList: Array<Object>;
  searchList: Array<Object>;
  searchTerm: string;
  constructor(private _flickrService: FlickrService) {
    this._flickrService.getFeed().subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: can you add ngmodule code ?

Comment: Have you known how to solve this problem? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone struggling to get this to work as I did, I finally got it to work in the following manner in Angular 5:

In app.module.ts add HttpClientJsonpModule

```
import {HttpClientModule, HttpClientJsonpModule, HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

imports: [
    ...

    HttpClientModule,
    HttpClientJsonpModule
...
]
```

in an api service I have:

```
getFlickrFeed() {
    const url = 'https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json&id=YOUR_ID&jsoncallback=JSONP_CALLBACK';

    return this.http.jsonp(url, 'JSONP_CALLBACK').pipe(
            tap(
                data => data
            )
        );
}
```

In my module:

```
    this.api.getFlickrFeed().subscribe(
        data => {

            this.flickrFeed = data['items'];

            console.log(this.flickrFeed);
        }
    );
```

Comment: Very nice, thank you for posting this. However i had to remove tap() from this code to make it work.

Comment: Glad it helped. Did you import tap btw? import {tap} from 'rxjs/operators';

Answer (score 1):

In order to have the `Jsonp` library work for me I've needed to end my queries with `callback=JSONP_CALLBACK`. So try updating your service to this...

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Jsonp, Http } from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/Rx'; // use rxjs as the observable

@Injectable()

export class FlickrService {

  url: string;
  apiKey: string = 'ffed2ef9dede27481c3195eea1be61eb';

  constructor(private _jsonp: Jsonp) {
    this.url = `https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?&api_key=${this.apiKey}&per_page=12&format=json`;
  }

  getFeed() {
    return this._jsonp.get(this.url+'&callback=JSONP_CALLBACK')
      .map(res => res.json()).catch(this._handleError);
  }

  searchTag(searchTerm: string) {
    return this._jsonp.get(this.url+'&tag='+searchTerm+'&callback=JSONP_CALLBACK')
      .map(res => res.json()).catch(this._handleError);
  }

  private _handleError(error: Response | any) {
    console.log(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.code);
  }
 }
```

Also, I'm not 100% sure if the `callback=JSONP_CALLBACK` *needs* to be the last argument of the query... But any and all documentation I've ever read has it there, so I've just done that and it has worked just fine for me.

Comment: I tried it, it didn't work :( There's an error showing in the console. `jsonFlickrFeed` is not defined.

Comment: `jsonFlickrFeed` isn't a function... Like, I have no idea where that comes from! Would you mind attaching a screenshot, or a full log of the error?

Comment: Updating my answer to have an error handler, would love to see the log from that too if possible.

Comment: Wait, are you importing the `JsonpModule` into your app's module?? (You need to do that!)

Comment: Yes, I did in the `app.module.ts`. The error appears to be the same like previous. http://imgur.com/a/2ozuV

Comment: The query URL doesn't match what it should be based on my service. Can you update your code to your current service?

Comment: Can you show me your code that works? I am getting the same error over and over again :(

Comment: I cannot access this link. It gives me "Page not found". Can you please, explain to me what was the issue, I am facing the same problem.