# Unable to pass customer header option while calling third party API from Angular application

Tags: angular, api, http-headers

I am trying to make API request to dunzo API for generating an access token and and it  is working on postman and getting a response but when I requesting through my Angular application so it is giving me some below error

> ```
> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.dunzo.in/api/v1/token' from origin 'http://localhost:4700' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field client-secret is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
> ```

my code is below

```
getAuthHeaderOptionGenerateToken() {
  let headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers = headers
    .set('client-secret', 'xxx')
    .set('client-id', 'xx')
    .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    .set('Accept', 'application/json')
    .set('Accept-Language', 'en_US');

  let option = {
    headers: headers
  };
  return option
}


getAuthToken() {
  return this.http.get < any > (this.api_Url + 'api/v1/token', this.getAuthHeaderOptionGenerateToken());
}
```

Thanks for your any response.

Comment: The browser is blocking your request as the API that your App is hitting is on a different origin. Can you check if the Dunzo API supports `JSONP`? If not, you'll probably have to proxy this `GET` request via a custom proxy endpoint. You can use https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ for testing. But if I were you, I'd implement one on my own as we're supposed to pass in confidential info like `client-id` and `client-secret` as custom headers.

Comment: @SiddAjmera Thanks for your reply so you mean I need to create a node sever for that ?

Comment: First check if they allow `JSONP`. If they do, send a `JSONP` instead of a `GET`. If they don't, then implement a proxy(can be a node, java or any other backend tech.) You can read through **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52797668/2622292)** if you want to know how to make a `JSONP` request in Angular. Hope this helps :)

Comment: ok but I am making request through the postman and sending client-id and client-secret in header then it working and giving response.

Comment: CORS is a browser based policy. So you'd get the error only when you try to make that request via a browser. You can read more about **[CORS here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)**

Comment: @KuldeepKoranga you getting response from trying in the postman because you are using HTTPS. In locally hosted angular web app you are using HTTP only. API doenst allow that sort of HTTP communication.

Comment: @SelakaN Thanks so now  I am not able to figure it out how should I make request

Comment: Should I create my own server for proxy? or else ?

Comment: This has to be enabled via your API. If it is not yours try adding CORS in your request headers `set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');` If this didnt work out you have to enable it from the API instead

Comment: Better to handle it at API side